# Place all app icons on one home screen instead of two on Redmi Note 10 (MIUI)

Tags: xiaomi, home-screen-shortcuts, home-screen, miui

I just switched from Xiaomi Redmi Note 9 to the Note 10. I haven't started installing apps on the 10, but already the home screen is split into 2 pages.

[image]
[image]

On my old phone, everything was on one screen.

How do I fix this? I'd also like to get rid of the "weather, time, and search bar" theme, it's taking up too much space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out you can long press those elements to get rid of them, then move the icons to the 1st screen and it will collapse to 1 screen.